# How to make sure a loopfile is only mounted once?

Tags: mount, loop-device

When mounting a filesystem image via `mount -o loop`, is there any mechanism to prevent the same file to be mounted a second time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific command that may stop the file to be mounted several times with **different** mountpoints, but you may use this script to not mount it if it is already mounted:

```
#!/bin/bash
mount |grep -qF "$1" || mount "$1" $2 -o loop
```

the first parameter is a file to mount, and second is a mount point to use.

Comment: Hrm, so that's suboptimal... `test $(losetup -j "$1" | wc -l) -eq 0 && mount "$1" $2 -o loop` will check for a loopdevice even if it's unmounted by the way.